# Adding screen brightness controls to android application

Tags: java, android

I am looking to add controls to adjust screen brightness locally in my app menu but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have seen examples to max-out or dim brightness but I am looking to add controls so that the user can control and set the brightness level. Does anyone have any examples, tutorials, source code, or just a place to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 27):

[The internet](http://almondmendoza.com/2009/05/23/changing-the-screen-brightness-programatically-in-cupcake/) claims this works, I haven't tried it though:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 100 / 100.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: That works from an Activity...any idea how to do it from a widget?  The Power Manager widget for Android 2.0 does it.  I want to be able to do it from my widget.

Comment: Notice, that it may don't work in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611287/changing-screen-brightness-on-a-htc-sense-device

Answer (score 10):

You can change the user's brightness setting like this (make sure you declare permission for WRITE_SETTINGS in the manifest)

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
                        android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightpref);
```

The documentation calls that setting from 0 to 255. I am trying to figure out whether it shuts the screen off at 0, as at one point I had a widget installed with a slider and you'd cause the screen to shut off if you set it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered by a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136880/android-brightness-change).

The only difference is that you will want to tie the **screenBrightness** member to the value of a user interface control.

Note that this might not work as expected on devices that have auto-dimming sensors.