# Control screen brightness in android using " Background Service"

Tags: android, android-widget

**Problem:-**

I want to control the brightness of screen using a background service in android.

**Existing Solutions:-**

There are similar question posted in the form in below link:-

[Adding screen brightness controls to android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application)

**Why existing solution will not work?**

All the solution provided in the link works well with an **Activity**, but I want to write a **Background Service** which controls the brightness of the screen.

So can you someone please help me find a solution on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just so we can help give you a better answer, what would you like to achieve with doing this in a background service? Is it for a widget?

Comment: no its not a widget. I want to switch on and off the screen light based on different application use. For eg:- if a phone call comes switch of the light in 4 sec. But this is activity dependent. I want a independent service which monitor different application and change the screen light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your service, start an activity and finish() it real fast!

Comment: Sorry for my later reply. 

I have tried to start the activity and close it in the oncreatre() method, but as I close the application all the changes I have made to modify the screen brightness has no effect. 

The solution to this problem is to create a transparent activity.

Thanks for giving right direction.

Comment: It doesn't work perfect. Because the activity to refresh will stay in task-list which names "recently" normally. In order to avoid this we must add two attributes on activity to refresh in the mainifast 
See here https://github.com/XinyueZ/brightnessdemo
.... 
android:taskAffinity="com.schautup.brightness.REFRESH"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
....