# Making a click-through Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, window

I'm trying to adjust the brightness of my phone programmatically. I've got an Activity in my app which is translucent to do this, however users can't click through it to the activity/window beneath it. I kill this activity as soon as the brightness is set, however I want to do more work in this activity (such as gradual brightness adjustment) which requires some time, and I don't want the user tapping at their phone wondering why their actions aren't being registered.

So basically, I need to either create a mock Window which will successfully allow me to adjust screen brightness without being displayed, or work out how to make an Activity click-through. I'm not sure how to do either.

BTW, this is the code making the brightness adjustments in the Activity:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, Math.round(SOME_BRIGHTNESS * 255f));

Window window = getWindow(); 
window.getAttributes().screenBrightness = SOME_BRIGHTNESS;
window.setAttributes(window.getAttributes());

float sysBrightPer = getSystemBrightness(getApplicationContext());   

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         try {
             sleep(BRIGHT_TIMEOUT);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finish();
    }
}.start();
```

Any advice?

P.S. I found this app on the market. I wonder if the way this has been achieved would help me? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor

Comment: I didn't consider doing that, but for good reason, because the API level is much too high for my target market.

Comment: I've seen you got a solution. But anyway you can use a Fragmentation official compatibility library to use them on any API level :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hah! That app did help me, if only because it led me to this solution!
[Brightness Screen Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286075/brightness-screen-filter)

For the click lazy, use this:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: By curiosity: This makes an click-through activity?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it does.

Comment: Yep, it makes the an click-through activity. But, every view in this activity will also be a click-through. How can I still intercept view clicks (in the upper most activity)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this no longer works in 4.0+, if applied to the window itself (presumably to the prevent use of activity class methods like onkey from a transparent overlay). However one can still use windowmanager.addview or layoutinflater.inflate to add a custom view class which extends viewgroup, and if you use layoutparams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE in adding or inflating this view, it will be click-through, and remain on top even when the activity that called it goes into onpause.

Answer (score 0):

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`

If you want to intercept touches on specific views you can use the window manager to add a view with different flags:
e.g.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(...);
getWindowManager().addView(myButton,params);
```