# Set brightness below the system limit using alpha and save value

Tags: android

I've been trying to set the brightness under the limit of Android settings. There are two similar apps in Google Play doing this:

- [Shades](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.shades&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGVjb2RlLmV5ZXNmcmVlLnNoYWRlcyJd)
- [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmhheG9yIl0)

The second one, even allows to use the phone with a black screen, just what I need in my app.

There are a lot of other questions about brightness but not to set it under this system limit, and I've found one question asking almost the same but not helping me:
[Brightness Screen Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286075/brightness-screen-filter)

So after a lot of search I've got following code:

```
int brightness=0; //0 to 255, so I set it to a low level (not enough for me)
ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();  

//set the system brightness value, and if active, disable auto mode.
System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);  
System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);  

//previous lines don't set the brightness to the current screen so we set it like this: 
LayoutParams layoutpars = getWindow().getAttributes();  
layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255; 

//Now we have brightness to the minimum allowed by Android but
//to achieve what these apps do, I have to reduce alpha of the window to the min
//then the screen is black like I want, and totally usable!
layoutpars.alpha=0.05f;
window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
```

Here the alpha is the key, this is doing what I want, but only for current window/screen, and I need to save to the system this alpha as default, like I'm doing with the brightness and the Manual mode for applying everywhere.

Do you know how I should do this? I'm unable to find a value "System.SCREEN_ALPHA" to set it with System.putInt or another way to do this.

In the other question I linked before, pheelicks replied with a suggestion of using a transparent non-touchable over screen, but this is not working for me, and the result does not give the feeling of a turned off screen like previous apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey ! How your problem gets solved ?? I m having the same requirement !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to implemented this feature just inside my app with alpha. So I couldn't solve the initial question at all....

Anyways, in the end seems that the solution to this question is the one Pheelicks replied here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4287597/1667990

-This is launching an activity to be always on top,

-with alpha to 0.0f so it be transparent,

-that redirects the touch to the activity behind:

```
//Let touches go through to apps/activities underneath.
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

-And most important thing not explained in the previous link, is to set the dim behind our window to 1 (like the dim in a messagebox, but setting to the max to be black behind :D )

```
window.setDimAmount ((float)1.0) ;
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

I haven't tried that and decided not to do it in my app as it could bring unexpected behavior in my circumstances, but I think it should definitely work, if anyone try please add your feedback!