# How to change window color of android?

Tags: android, graphics, window-managers

how can I change screen colors like the following application does:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netmanslab.sa

I wasn't able to find any      WindowManager or ScreenManager method to do so.

Comment: This is similar to [Brightness Screen Filter][1]. Just vary the ARGB value.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286075/brightness-screen-filter

Comment: @alan but still I cannot see any function that would change ARGB of Window and in the solution which include adding a view does not seems to be promising when background changes.

Comment: The solution involves running your activity on top of any other apps. The activity is semi-transparent so you can see through it, giving an illusion that the screen color is changed. By setting appropriate LayoutParams you can enable click-through your activity so other apps can run normally. You can change the background color of the activity to adjust its ARGB.