# Create a simple screen filter

Tags: android, filter, brightness

I saw this **post** [Brightness Screen Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286075/brightness-screen-filter)
which describes how to create a simple screen filter.
 That code used

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
try {
  IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(
   ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));

  if (hardware != null) {
    hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);
  }
 } catch (RemoteException doe) {          
  }        
 }
```

But i could not find the `IHardwareService.jar`
Can anyone explain me the code that i should use to create this simple app?

Providing the jar file would be also appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found your jar file. 
It can be obtained in this 
[link](http://code.google.com/p/batterywidget/source/browse/trunk/a_batterywidget/hardware09.jar?r=9)

by clicking "View raw file" on the right bottom side of the page.

Hope it helps you.

If the link is broken, just warn me.

Comment: when i use the code the app crashes... are you sure that this is the correct jar file?

Comment: When does your app crash? Could you show the stack trace?