# How to control screen birghtness with slider in android

Tags: android

I want users to be able to control the birghtness with a slider. Please answer in the simplest way because im a noob when it comes to android.

Answer (score 5):

Controlling the screen brightness has been through here many times, for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application).

Now, the easiest way to get a slider control is to use the [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) widget, which comes pretty close. Then you just hook up the [OnSeekBarChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener)) event to your function which sets the brightness to your desired value.

Comment: because I don't have any? Besides it's your "homework" to write the final code, can't really rely on people to do your job for you.