# How to get current screen's brightness in Android code dynamiclly?

Tags: android

How to get current screen's brightness in Android code dynamiclly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding screen brightness controls to android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application)

Comment: have you got a way to get it?

Answer (score 14):

Hi to get the current brightness level of the android system you can use this code:

```
try {
    float curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
    getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nope, it reads current settings of brightness, not the current brightness.

Comment: @greenoldman That is true. Current brightness can be retrieved by `getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness`. If however this current brightness is < 0 this means that application uses the current settings for brightness (which can be loaded by the means provided in current answer)

Comment: `getInt()` Method return Int value.But Brightness store as a float.Better to use `getFloat()`

Comment: @Jimmer Nope, as it returns `The screen backlight brightness between 0 and 255.`

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat, Android can change brightness automatically (hint: dim).

Comment: @greenoldman So, we have here to set the settings of `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL` to avoid that, right ?

Answer (score 5):

This was asked a while ago but just to expand on fiction's answer:

settings.screenBrightness will return -1 if it has not been previously overwritten in code. This is correct behaviour as setting screenBrightness to -1 will set the brightness to the current system brightness level.

This system brightness can be changed by the user at any time, so there is probably not much use in storing the actual value, if you are just trying to return the brightness to its original value, as the actual value might be "out of date".

Comment: This answer should get more votes since it's probably what most people are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can read content of this system file

> /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness

This value is current screen brightness within range 0-255

Answer (score -1):

Acording to this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness

you can change brightness by

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams settings = getWindow().getAttributes();
settings.screenBrightness = newValue;
getWindow().setAttributes(settings);
```

*Also refer Hamiora answer for further explanation.*

Comment: hi, float savedBrightness = settings.screenBrightness; cannot get the current brightness but whether is overrided by app, and i try it but always get -1.0f from it, because I do not override it!

Comment: @yuankai You should perform additional check. If your `savedBrightness` < 0 that means that application uses the default brightness. The default brightness level can be retrieved by MidhunVP's answer. (just keep in mind that `settings.screenBrightness` ranges from 0f to 1f while system setting has values from 0 to 255)