# Should I reopen the camera before changing the Surface dimension

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on a custom camera app and using `FrameLyout` for displaying preview. In one part of the app I have to change the `Preview` size and `FrameLayout` size dynamically. This is the steps I am follwing before changing `Framelayout` size

- Stop the `preview`
- Change `preview` and `framelyout` size
- Start the `preview` again.

I did this successfully but preview is darker than earlier preview, Please let me know what could be the reason.

Should I reopen the camera before changing the `FrameLayout` dimension?

Comment: Is there code you can post? I have a hard time imagining what this may look like.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a camera preview involves the following steps :- 
 
1.Getting an instance of Camera by :
 `Camera camera = Camera.open(cameraId)` 
2.Pass a surface to this camera instance which would be used for displaying the preview by 
`camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)`

3.Set some parameters if you need like 
`Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();`
`params.setFlashMode(String)` ,
 `params.setPreviewSize(int , int)`
`camera.setParameters(params)`

4.Start the camera preview by calling :-
`camera.startPreview`

Thats all you need to do to start a camera preview.

As per your requirement ,  when you want to change the surface and preview size, do the following :- 
a) Stop the preview :- `camera.stopPreview()` 
b) **Repeat steps 2-4 as given above.**

> Camera close might not be needed unless you switch from Back/Front or
>   vice versa.

Comment: I tried that.. It will not work until unless I release the camera and open again.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are performing various camera operations?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy everything you did to start the preview and placing it in the FrameLayout at the biggining of your code, ecxept change your preview and FrameLayout, and call the new method when you want to make the change. This way everything should look the same, since you are completely restarting the preview.

Comment: Yes, and then run your new code that will take control of the camera

Comment: Yes but at least it will work. Besides that, try looking at your code up to that point and seeing if there's anyway it could have messed up the preview.

Comment: This problem occurs only in my nexus 5(Android L) device

Comment: You can try to get the camera brightness before making your changes, then when you start the camera again you can set the brightness to your previous state. Use this for changing the brightness https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544987/how-to-get-current-screens-brightness-in-android-code-dynamiclly

Comment: screen brightness has nothing to do with camera brightness because I am getting dark picture

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily even have to stop preview here; a SurfaceView will automatically scale the output of the camera into its size, so as long as you maintain the same aspect ratio, you should have no problem in just changing the frame layout size.

If you are changing the aspect ratio, then you do need to at least stop preview, change the preview size to a matching aspect ratio with Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize, and then start preview again.

Does stopping and starting preview without changing layout change the preview brightness? If so, it sounds like a bug in that particular device's camera implementation.

Comment: I am changing the preview size and surface size and also restarting the preview but still getting dark preview