# How to set brightness through ADB on nexus 7

Tags: android, adb, android-source, brightness, nexus-7

I found some info on the web:

`echo 1 /sys/devices/platform/flashlight.0/leds/flashlight/brightness`

But on my Nexus 7 (flashed an AOSP), I couldn't find that directory.

Any idea about which file should I write to? Is this doable?

After `ls /sys/devices/platform`, I got:

```
LID
alarm
arm-pmu.0
bcm4330_rfkill
bcmdhd_wlan.1
bluesleep
fiq_debugger.0
fsl-tegra-udc
gpio-keys.0
grouper_misc
leds-gpio
oprofile-perf.0
power
power.0
pwm-backlight
ram_console
reg-dummy
reg-fixed-voltage.1
reg-fixed-voltage.10
reg-fixed-voltage.11
reg-fixed-voltage.2
reg-fixed-voltage.3
reg-fixed-voltage.4
reg-fixed-voltage.6
reg-fixed-voltage.8
regulatory.0
sdhci-tegra.2
sdhci-tegra.3
serial8250
snd-soc-dummy
spdif-dit.0
spdif-dit.1
spi_tegra.0
spi_tegra.3
tegra-ehci.1
tegra-i2c.0
tegra-i2c.1
tegra-i2c.2
tegra-i2c.3
tegra-i2c.4
tegra-nvmap
tegra-otg
tegra-pcm-audio
tegra-se
tegra-snd-rt5640.0
tegra30-ahub
tegra30-dam.0
tegra30-dam.1
tegra30-dam.2
tegra30-hda
tegra30-i2s.1
tegra30-i2s.3
tegra30-i2s.4
tegra30-spdif
tegra_camera
tegra_pwm.0
tegra_rtc
tegra_smmu
tegra_uart.1
tegra_uart.2
tegra_uart.3
tegra_uart.4
tegra_wdt
uevent
```

Comment: Try pwm-backlight! (just a guess)

Comment: @thiagolr Good guess! I found it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the **pwm-backlight**!

Comment: Can you please provide a full command example of how to use it?

Comment: I don't have a Nexus 7 to test it, but it should be something like this: adb shell "echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/pwm-backlight"

Answer (score 41):

There is a new binary shipping with Android Jellybean 4.2, which can be used to directly read/write to the system settings provider, accessible via command line.

For example: in order to increase brightness of the screen, use below command:

> adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 200

[Read more about `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS) Note that the range of values is [0 - 255]

Comment: You saved me, thanks! Is there a place where i can found commands like this one?

Comment: For more settings: `settings list namespace`. ('namespace' is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive.)

Comment: additionally `settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0` may be needed

Comment: Godlike answer.

Comment: This command doesn't work on my Sony XBR X850G Android TV. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 2):

The range of values is not necessarily from 0 - 255. On my OnePlus for example
it ranges from 0-2047. If you want to know yours just set the brightness slider to max and
then type: `adb shell settings get system screen_brightness.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this adb command to set screen brightness

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 255
```

and if your device has auto brightness setting then use this command first

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for the latest Nexus 7 (2013) for me. But this answer explains the way to find what you are looking for on any version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13492336

However we need to note that in order to change any of this you need to have **root** access.