# Flashing Screen in Android

Tags: android

I made a android project, now my project has a need to set up a alarm type, like blinking screen for which user can see that screen is blinking,

Flashing screen means, screen back light is turn off/on regularly.

Like we make a thread and after every 500 milliseconds we toggle the screen light.

How i do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To modify screen brightness, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application)
- For repeating schedulded events you can make use of the standard java [Timer/TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or simply play with android [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable,delay)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

For a short introduction to the later, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android).

Happy coding!