# button to manage the brightness of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to create an application  always active (ie never goes in the background), with a button that when is pressed reduces the screen brightness. I state that I'm no expert in programming in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set screen BRIGHTNESS o button click as:

**FIRST WAY:**

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
       getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
   setBrightness(curBrightnessValue-25);//set BRIGHTNESS
  }
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {  
    try {  
      IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(  
      ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));  
      if (hardware != null) {  
        hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);  
      }  
    } catch (RemoteException doe) {            
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"></uses-permission>
```

**SECOND WAY:**

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
   getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
   int SysBackLightValue = curBrightnessValue-25;
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
   android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
   SysBackLightValue);
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

and finally for other way to set brightness see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application) post