# Finding source code of battery saving mode in android?

Tags: android

Greeting, how to do battery saving mode that let user to create, modified and delete for android? Example: screen brightness adjustment,turn off WiFi,Bluetooth option, and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all the options, whether WIFI is on, bluetooth is on, and for Screen brightness refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793680/5567009, may be these things helpful to you.